# Trying to create a Sales_item.h class w/ CodeBlocks

Tags: c++

So im still new to programming and bought the C++ primer 5th edition book to try and help me out.
I am stuck at this part of creating a class. I am currently using CodeBlocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_Item.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Sales_item book;
   cin >> book;
   cout << book << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was able to create a class file but unable to run the program because of my cin>> book; It says that error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream'

Comment: What are you stuck on?  You didn't explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does the file `Sales_Item.h` have anything in it?

Comment: Assuming that is your only error -- the error implies that something is wrong/missing in the file Sales_Item.h.  Solving this problem requires looking at that file too.

Comment: [Sales_Item.h](https://github.com/amidvidy/learning/blob/master/cpp-primer/Sales_item.h)

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be helpful to see the Sales_Item header.
I can only guess and I think you have variables defined in your class/struct like int or string etc. What you are doing is getting an input of a certain type but only passing it to the class which is probably not your intention. You have to call a variable from the class.
Example:

```
Sales_item book;
cin >> book.price;
```

In this case you would input the price of the book

Comment: One can `cin` directly to an object if `operator>>()` has been implemented. It hasn't been, per the error message. You're also assuming an all public class and not a struct? The book they have wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: yea so im completely confused on this part. Im using the 5th edition c++ primer and it says to create the code uptop and create a class. I think I made a class 
#include "Sales_item.h"

Sales_item::Sales_item()
{
  
}

Sales_item::~Sales_item()
{
    //dtor
}

Comment: Put this stuff in the question. And if you haven't finished the chapter, you're likely just asking questions about an incomplete example.

Comment: I removed the class example. I think it was to confusing.

Comment: You're still making a false statement in your answer.